# Does minimum spend on bounty double rule apply for 500 point bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

At [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) descriptions of the rule includes

> Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500
>
> - Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation
>     on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third,
>     and so on).

Is this true for initial bounty being 500?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [bounty FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) (emphasis mine):

> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, you will have to double the amount each time (or more). That is, if your first bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200 and so on. **If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, you can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as you like (or as long as you have the rep).** This doubling applies only to bounties by the same user on the same question.

So, while you're required to double your amount in subsequent bounties, every subsequent bounty can never exceed 500.

Comment: So in other words: 
The minimum Bounty rises to a maximum minimum where the maximum minimum equals the maximum.

Comment: @BigM: I guess you could say that.

Comment: Maybe this could be clarified in the offical help page

Comment: Hopefully the clarification will be properly attributed to @BigM.

Comment: @BoltClock the real question is *can* you say that.

Comment: @Cullub definitely not quickly!